# Base and Derived class constructor polymorphism woes

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Sorry for the vague title.

I'm writing a set of classes, and im having trouble thinking of an intuitive way of  breaking up what is done in the base constructor and what is done in the derived constructor.

My problem is as follows:

All classes require steps A, C, and E to be completed in sequence. Therefore it made sense to put them in the base constructor.

Steps B and D are unique to each of the derived classes.

Unfortunately, B must be completed *after* A and *before* C, and similarily D must be completed *after* C and *before* E. These are OpenGL function calls and I am contrained to the ordering of them.

I originally tried something along the lines of this, hoping to encapsulate as much as possible in the base class:

```
public class MyBase
{
    MyBase()
    {
        A():
        B();
        C();
        D();
        E();  
    }
    void A() {...}
    void C() {...}
    void E() {...}
    virtual void B() = 0;
    virtual void D() = 0;
}

public class MyDerived : public MyBase
{
    MyDerived() : MyBase() {}
    void B() {...}
    void D() {...}
}
```

But that is not possible in C++...

Is there a more intuitive way of doing this other than:

```
public class MyBase
{
    MyBase() {}
    void A() {...}
    void B() {...}
    void C() {...}
}

public class MyDerived : public MyBase
{
    MyDerived()
    {
        A():
        B();
        C();
        D();
        E();  
    }
    void B() {...}
    void D() {...}
}
```

I am hoping to avoid as much code repetition as possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do these methods absolutely have to be called in the constructors? I often find that it is easier to just have an "initialize" method that is called post-construction. As long as every inherited class and member has a default constructor then doing it that way shouldn't cause any snags. If every class derives from a common base, you can even put them all on a vector and call the initialize method in a loop.

Comment: I think it's probably better to move `C` and `E` to the derived types.  I'm having a hard time imagining this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely want to call it in the constructor, and are not ok with calling it after, you can reduce the clutter a little bit by doing the below.

```
public class MyBase
{
    protected:
    void templateMethod()
    {
        A():
        B();
        C();
        D();
        E();  
    }
    private:
    void A() {...}
    void C() {...}
    void E() {...}
    virtual void B() = 0;
    virtual void D() = 0;
};

public class MyDerived : public MyBase
{
    MyDerived() : MyBase() {templateMethod();}
    void B() {...}
    void D() {...}
};
```

This is not quite a true template method pattern though, since now all the derived classes have to call it, instead of it being called once for the base class.

Comment: Just one question: in C++, is it guaranteed the vftable is initialized when MyDerived's ctor is invoked?  I believe it is not a defined behavior, hence invoking virtual methods in ctor can be dangerous.

Comment: @AdrianShum: When `MyDerived`'s constructor begins, the `vftable` is already updated to the right place.

Comment: @AdrianShum I believe that this is well defined to work up to the derived class, any derived-derived classes would cause issues. This will not work for a heirarchy where non leaf classes are not abstract

Answer (score 0):

Given that calling virtual function in constructor can be dangerous, is using macro an acceptable solution for you?

```
#define MY_BASE_INIT A();B();C();D();E();

public class MyBase
{
    MyBase() {}
    void A() {...}
    void C() {...}
    void E() {...}
}

public class MyDerived : public MyBase
{
    MyDerived()
    {
        MY_BASE_INIT
    }
    void B() {...}
    void D() {...}
}
```

Comment: how does putting the calls in a macro help? And how does MyBase get it's three methods called?

Comment: In fact it is simply the your 2nd solution.  I am simply putting the series of method invocation in a macro.  Please note that the macro is used in the ctor of derived class, not the base class

Comment: precisely, my question is, how is invoking from macro different from invoking directly, provided that the base constructor is empty? From the standpoint of the compiler, it should be the same

Comment: it is the same  :)  the difference is simply reduce of repetitive boiler-plate code as compared with your original 2nd method (and I thought that's what you are looking for as u said "I am hoping to avoid as much code repetition as possible.")